# Diplomatic visibility levels

Tags: civilization-6

In Civ 6 you can have a certain "Diplomatic Visibility" with another civilization. These give you notifications about certain events related with this civ. The levels are:

1. None
2. Limited
3. Open
4. Secret
5. Top secret

What are the different types of gossip you can get from each diplomatic visibility level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no exact listing anywhere of what level gives you what, it's more of a general amount of how much gossip you will get (and frankly it becomes an annoying amount late game).

> EDIT (Info moved from comments):
>
> Certain information is only available at certain levels. In the early
>   couple stages you only get access to things like war declaration,
>   denouncements and their first hidden agenda, and a vague idea of what
>   they think of you.
>
> By the higher tiers of visibility you begin to see the second agenda,
>   clearing land for wonders and war preparation - basically the higher
>   you get, the frequency increases and the more strategically value the
>   information becomes.

**Visibility** is the amount of information you are currently able to obtain about the other civilization.

When you click on the **Access Level** button, you will see in the bottom part of the UI, a breakdown of all active factors currently contributing to Visibility. You will also see what kind of info you share on this level, and what you may expect to see in the next level of visibility.

- **Arguably the most important things you learn through gossip and visibility are: when a nation clears land for a wonder, when they are preparing for a war, and when they denounce other nations. Each of those provide valuable strategic information about other nations.**

Visibility is provided by the following factors, which are cumulative:

- Sending a Trade Delegation or Establishing an Embassy. (These two are not cumulative)
- Having a Trade Route with them.
- Being Allies.
- Having a Spy create a Listening Post in one of their cities. This action does not stack with being Allies.
- Research Printing technology. This automatically gives you one level of Visibility with all nations.

The gossip part of the game doesn't have a lot of recorded detail to explain it, but you can get the gist of it through [the diplomacy tab of the wiki](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Diplomacy_(Civ6)).

Comment: Thanks! But I don't understand this: are there types of information (for example, denouncing other nations) available only at certain level, or the different levels only affect the frequency of updates?

Comment: Yes certain information is only available at certain levels. In the early couple you only get access to things like war declaration, denouncing and their first hidden agenda, and a vague idea of what they think of you. By the higher tiers of visibility you begin to see the second agenda, clearing land for wonders and war preparation - basically the higher you get, the frequency increases and the more strategically value the information becomes.

Comment: That's the information I was looking for when asked, it would be great if you could add it to the (accepted) answer :)

Comment: Yeah I can add it up there - I briefly touched on it, I'll add it to the part where I mention it